# Impersonation and Registry Manipulation in Vista\Win7

Tags: c++, winapi, registry, impersonation

I need to create a program that has access to **HKLM** when running in a non-admin session.  I have access to the admin credentials so impersonation seems to be an option.The sequence of Win32 calls is:

1. **LogonUser**
2. **ImpersonateLoggedOnUser**
3. **RegOpenKeyEx**
4. **RegCreateKeyEx**

The key is successfully created on XP/2003 and fails with 'Access Denied' on Vista/Win7. I am running as the same default domain user and impersonating the same domain admin in each of the scenarios.  The 'Access Denied' is being generated by **RegCreateKeyEx** and obviously the key isn't being created.

Anyone have a clue to why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to accomplish this is through multiple processes as Murray and Anders suggested. First you launch a process to launches another process with the CreateProcessAsLoggedOnUser with Admin credentials. Then you have to launch ANOTHER process using the ShellExecute function with "runas" specified as the verb. This allows for impersonation and elevation without a UAC dialog.

Answer (score 2):

An administrator on Windows Vista/7 doesn't have write access to HKLM by default either, they must elevate first.  See [Vista UAC: The Definitive Guide](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista-security/UAC__The_Definitive_Guide.aspx) for details on launching a new process elevated since you cannot elevate an existing process.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the username/password for a admin user, you could start a helper process with [CreateProcessWithLogonW()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682431(VS.85).aspx) and communicate with it using some kind of IPC (Pipes,shared memory+events etc)

As to why it fails on NT6, maybe your impersonation is not giving you a [high IL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb625964.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In Vista/Win7 the security has changed. See this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb530198.aspx) on registry virtualization.

Comment: Good article about registry virtualization and I realize that Microsoft is advocating the LUA scenario for new development of applications but shouldn't Administrators still have access to HKLM?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK to access to HKLM in Vista/Windows7 you must have administrator privilages.
Try to compile program with option - require administrator privilage, or just run program as administrator.